# prevent invisible form from being easily hacked

Tags: jquery, post, datatables, mpdf

### Summary

If a form is set to `display:none` and it's fields are populated with somewhat arbitrary  `html` code by javascript, what kind of data sanitizing/form security is required on submission?

### Background

I'm using the JQuery plugin [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) to reformat and display data subtotalled by group. It works great except for one small fly in the ointment: exporting the table to PDF (or other forms) through the [TableTools](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/) extension results in the original format rather than the grouped and subtotalled format.  After a [discussion](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/7443/pdf-output-of-grouped-rows-is-messed-up#Item_8) with the DataTables/TableTools author, I came to the conclusion that I needed to export a different way.

I made a button that submits the modified table html rather than the original html to a php script that uses mpdf to create the pdf file.  It does this by populating an "invisible" form and then submitting it. It works great.

But I'm concerned that having an invisible form that submits html leaves me wide open to abuse. What are the best ways to ensure that the POSTed input is what I'm expecting when the input is arbitrary?

### Code

```
<!--HTML-->
<button name='Make PDF' id='butPDF'/>

<form action='makepdf.php' method='post' name='mpdf' 
      id='mpdf' style='display:none'>
  <textarea name='pdf_html'></textarea>
</form>
```

---

```
//javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.datatable').dataTable( {
    //process table into desired format      
  });

  $('button#butPDF').onClick(
    function(){
       var html= get_my_stuff();//collect up the desired bits
       $('textarea[name="pdf_html"]').val(html);
       $('form#mpdf).submit();
    }
  );
});
```

---

```
<?php
include(_MPDF_PATH . "mpdf.php");

$html=$_POST['pdf_html'];
$stylesheet = file_get_contents(LOCAL_INCLUDE.'css/mpdf.css');

$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1,true);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 2,false);
$mpdf->Output('myfile.pdf','D'); //D for download
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add another form field and check to see if that has been filled in as well. Check to see if is filled after submit, then you know the form has been forcibly filled by a bot.